# PHP: Pass an array by reference in a class and use it in other methods

Tags: php, arrays, oop, reference

I've the following snippet:

```
public function __construct($s, $e, &$v, &$rv, $needle, $parser, $id) {

        $this->start = $s;
        $this->end = $e;

        $this->vett = $v;
        $this->resVett = &$rv;

        $this->id = $id;

        $this->needle = $needle;

        $this->parser = $parser;
    }

    public function pushResult($result) {

        $this->resVett[] = $result;
    }
```

When I call pushResult the value is properly inserted but the original array, the one referenced by rv, is not affected. 
Have you any idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a very sane design in any case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe the problem relies elsewhere. I checked your code with an easy example

```
<?php
class Example {

     public $value = [];
     public $reference = [];

     public function __construct($value, &$reference) {
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->reference =& $reference;
     }

     public function pushResult($result) {
        $this->reference[] = $result;
        $this->value[] = $result;
    }
}

$value = ['test'];
$reference = ['test'];

$example = new Example($value, $reference);
$example->pushResult('result');

echo 'Is Value variable same?';
var_dump($value === $example->value);

echo 'Is Reference variable same?';
var_dump($reference === $example->reference);
```

and passing the reference like you do it should work

Comment: You can check the code online here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/41aabbf7f8ef263df6319914f1b575c59c52ee56